# jQuery Array with objects, splice not working as expected

Tags: jquery

**Hi there,**

I Have an Array on my page. In this arrays I insert an object after I click on it. However, I seem to have issues with removing it from the array. This is strange, since the exact same code seems to work for another array: there it indeed does remove the object. I Remove the object by index:

**Code on top of my JS file.**

```
var f__packages = [];
```

**On click, insert as object in Array.**

```
 var packages = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      packages['obj'] = results[i].id;
    }
f__packages.push(packages);
```

Until here, it works fine. It inserts an object in my array. However now comes the tricky part. When I click on it again, the object should be removed from the array.

```
 var index__pid = f__packages.findIndex(y => y.obj==value);
 console.log(index__pid);
 f__packages.splice(index__pid, index__pid);
```

It does find the correct index, and sometimes it does remove the object with that index from the array. However, not always. It seems to have the most issues with the last object in the array. When there are no more (also index: 0), it fails.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why the loop if there is only one property (`obj`) in the object? The "click" part is the same as: `f__packages.push({ 'obj': results[results.length - 1].id })`

Comment: @Andreas Since there is more in the loop, however I removed this for easy reading purposes. It adds the rest to another array.

Comment: The `.splice(index__pid, index__pid)` makes not much sense... The syntax is: `array.splice(start, *deleteCount*)`, hence you're removing `index__pid` elements starting from `index__pid`

Comment: Actually, I just discovered that I'm doing it all wrong indeed. The second parameter should be the amount it should remove. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
f__packages.splice(index__pid, index__pid);
```

Change it to:

```
f__packages.splice(index__pid, 1);
```

---

> [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
>
> The `splice()` method changes the contents of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `array.splice(start)`
>   `array.splice(start, deleteCount)`
>   `array.splice(start, deleteCount, item1, item2, ...)`
>
> `start`
>   Index at which to start changing the array (with origin 0). If greater than the length of the array, actual starting index will be set to the length of the array. If negative, will begin that many elements from the end of the array (with origin 1) and will be set to 0 if absolute value is greater than the length of the array.
>
> `deleteCount` *(Optional)*
>   An integer indicating the number of old array elements to remove. If `deleteCount` is 0, no elements are removed. In this case, you should specify at least one new element. If `deleteCount` is greater than the number of elements left in the array starting at start, then all of the elements through the end of the array will be deleted.
>   If `deleteCount` is omitted, or if its value is larger than `array.length - start`, then all of the elements beginning with start index on through the end of the array will be deleted.
>
> `item1, item2, ...` *(Optional)*
>   The elements to add to the array, beginning at the start index. If you don't specify any elements, `splice()` will only remove elements from the array.